# Spawning urdf with a launch file & PID controls

Tags: urdf

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to launch my world file with my custom robot spawned at launch, I follow the urdf tutorial at Gazebo main page, but the model won't spawn.

```
<launch>
  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find kuka_kr3_gazebo)/worlds/kuka_kr3.world"/>
<!-- more default parameters can be changed here -->
</include>
 <!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->

 <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find kuka_kr3_description)/urdf/model.urdf"/>
 <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find kuka_kr3_description)/urdf/model.urdf -urdf -param robot_description -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.1 -model kuka_kr3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

The launch file runs 'correctly' but there is no robot model, I think this piece of log from console might be connected:

```
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [7932]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [7940]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [7950]
process[spawn_urdf-4]: started with pid [7958]
SpawnModel script started
No handlers could be found for logger "rosout"
[ INFO] [1507552317.153725427]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1507552317.154071045]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
```

I can spawn the robot model using rosrun command

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find kuka_kr3_description`/urdf/model.urdf -urdf -x 0 -y 0 -z 1 -model kuka_kr3
```

but this isn't exactly what I want.

I am also wondering if that may cause problems that I have with a controller - the values of PID from controller aren't the same as the ones in Gazebo, and I think that causes problems when I try to control it from Moveit.

EDIT that part with the controller has not been connected with that, but the spawning problem still remains.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17460/spawning-urdf-with-a-launch-file-&-pid-controls/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In your launchfile you pass to many arguments to the spawn_model node and you should convert the robot description with xacro.
First you should load the robot_description with xacro:

`<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find kuka_kr3_description)/urdf/model.urdf"/>`

Second you should give the correct args to spawn_model:

`<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.1 -model kuka_kr3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>`

or if you like it fancy you can do something like this:

`<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find kuka_kr3_description)/urdf/model.urdf"/>`

`<param name="dummy_to_generate_gazebo_urdf_file" command="rosrun xacro xacro.py -o /tmp/robot.gazebo.urdf $(find kuka_kr3_description)/urdf/model.urdf" />`

`<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file /tmp/robot.gazebo.urdf -urdf -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.1 -model kuka_kr3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>`

If all is not working there might be a problem with the `$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`. Could be that Gazebo can not find the mesh files.

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1